# Как вывести подкатегории с ссылкой и изображением под названием категории в woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

[image: пример]

Как я могу вывести под название категории её подкатегории с картинками и ссылкой для перехода? Категорий и подкатегории много и они все разные, по этому по указанию одного id не совсем походит.

Answer (score 0):

Создай  под каждой категории отдельный блок где будут размещаться под категории данной категории и скрой. При нажатии на любых из категории будешь раскрывать соответсвующий блок.

```js
 $('.show-btn').on('click', function(){
    const thisDropDownID = $(this).attr('dropdown');
    $('#' + thisDropDownID).toggleClass('active');
  });
```

```css
.dropdown{
  display:none;
}
.active {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <span dropdown="gaz-gril" class="show-btn">Газовый гриль</span>
    <div class="dropdown" id="gaz-gril">
       <div>
        <a href="#">Гозовый гриль 1</a>
        <a href="#">Гозовый гриль 2</a>
       </div>
    </div>
  <div>
  <div>
    <span dropdown="gaz-gril-2" class="show-btn">Газовый гриль 2</span>
    <div class="dropdown" id="gaz-gril-2">
       <div>
        <a href="#">Гозовый гриль 3</a>
        <a href="#">Гозовый гриль 4</a>
       </div>
    </div>
  <div>
<div>
```